# Getting the entire List of Stock Symbols that the getSymbols function will contain

Tags: r, quantmod

```
library(quantmod)
```

For example:

```
> getSymbols("BRK.B",from="2010-01-01",to="2020-02-17")
```

will give me an error:

```
Warning: BRK.B download failed; trying again.
Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "BRK.B", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE,  : 
  Unable to import “BRK.B”.
BRK.B download failed after two attempts. Error message:
HTTP error 404.
```

I don't know why it doesn't contain Berkshire Hathaway.

But my question is, where can I get the complete list of stock symbols that the function, getSymbols, will return data for for the past 5 years or so?

Answer (score 3):

`getSymbols` doesn't contain any symbols. You need to specify which symbols you want. And the return will be dependent on the source you choose. Default is yahoo. But there are a few others, like tiingo, alphavantage, bloomberg, etc., but need api's to connect to.

In case of BRK B, you made a typo, it should be BRK-B, not BRK.B (at least for the yahoo source).

```
getSymbols("BRK-B",from="2010-01-01",to="2020-02-17")
```